# How do we use getBalance() function in FA1.2 token contract in SmartPy?

Tags: node, smart-contracts, smartpy

https://smartpy.io/demo/index.html?template=FA1.2.py&source=post_page---------------------------
This is the token contract link. 
It is deployed on the `https://babylonnet.SmartPy.io` node with the contract address as `KT1WYnCtS6ofvSgXNFKDNGqvgWushAEnZWWh`

Below is the link to the complete result of the contract deployment.
https://anotepad.com/notes/8k64a72p

Below is the result of the transaction which calls the getBalance function.
https://anotepad.com/notes/44giwqrn

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use this to play with it (skip the Lorentz part but start with the smart contract).

https://assets.tqtezos.com/token-contracts/1-fa12-lorentz#interactusingtezos-client